# Overlay multiple pages - like when you click on a Facebook photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

Maybe an easy question, but my knowledge of javascript is still very small.
I have an website with 4 pages. On each page I want to make a div clickable which opens a overlay screen. But every overlay screen has different text, because the content (text and images) in de overlay screen are an extension of the text in the clicable div. Now I kan make each div clickable, but I don't know how to open the right overlay screen.

I was thinking to give the overlay class a ID name, like pagename-1 (first div on a page). Then select the ID with document.getElementById() or something and add it to the javascript. But I don't know how to do exactly, because my id's contains a pagename + a number (for the overview)...

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/52osrbcu/

HTML

```
<div class="trigger-overlay">
<img src="http://www.queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/img/portfolios/card/4.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</div>                                  

<div class="trigger-overlay">           
<img src="http://www.queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/img/portfolios/logo/5.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</div>


     <div class="overlay overlay-slidedown" id="pagename-1">
            <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
      <p>
      text1
      </p>
        </div>

     <div class="overlay overlay-slidedown" id="pagename-2">
            <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
      <p>
      text2
      </p>
        </div>


        <script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/js/classie.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
/* Overlay style */
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(7,6,10,0.9);
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Overlay closing cross */
.overlay .overlay-close {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: url(http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/img/cross.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: 200%;
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Effects */
.overlay-slidedown {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.4s;
}

.overlay-slidedown.open {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

Javascript

```
  (function() {
        var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),
            overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
            closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
            transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
                'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition': 'transitionend'
            },
            transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
            support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

        function toggleOverlay() {
            if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
                classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
                classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
                var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                    if( support.transitions ) {
                        if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                        this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                    }
                    classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
                };
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                else {
                    onEndTransitionFn();
                }
            }
            else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
                classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
            }
        }
        for (x=0;x<triggerBttn.length;x++) {
            triggerBttn[x].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
        }
        closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    })();
```

Eventually I want something like the overlay on Facebook in the news feed. An other thing I have to edit is make scrolling not possible when the overlay screen is visible.

Comment: For your last question, just put `overflow:hidden;` on your body when you click on one and make sure you go back to `overflow:auto;` when you remove the overlay.  Also, the technical word that might be easier to search is called a 'modal'

Comment: Yeah I see, you have modals with bootstrap. Maybe that's easier to use instead of this. I gonna try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend using jQuery for this as it would make your code a lot cleaner, but if you want to stick to pure Javascript then I would use attributes, as the make more semantic sense for your problem than ids. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52osrbcu/1/. Here is the modified code:

In the HTML file:

```
<div class="trigger-overlay" pagename="1">
```

In the Javascript file:

```
function toggleOverlay() {
      console.log(this.getAttribute("pagename"));
```

I just printed the pagename attribute to the console but you can use that in an if statement to select the correct text to show.

Comment: You recommend jQuery for the whole thing? Problem is I'm a beginner so this is also code from another source I am editing. 
But what you say about that if statement, how will it look? 
if(this.getAttribute("pagename") === 1) {
//show text
}
and then for each number?

Because at the end, I have to made around 40-50 overlays, I perform to put the text in the HTML file

Comment: I mean, you can this in just Javascript for now, but you can do it much cleaner in Jquery. I would say do this part in Javascript but you should probably learn Jquery for future projects. Codecademy has a great class on Jquery, which is where I learned it

Comment: For you other question, why not make an array and then parse the pagename attribute using `parseInt(this.getAttribute("pagename"))` and then saying something like `var text = somearray[parseInt(this.getAttribute("pagename"))]`